# Docker command works in terminal but not script

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

After following instructions to setup a blockchain system, my colleague moved everything into a script since it needs to be run multiple times.

However as a script it fails on the following line:

```
docker exec -it cli bash
```

When entering it into a terminal use user and path change to `root@someaddress` which I assume is the new docker container. Then `-it cli bash` should create a new bash environment to run the rest of the commands.

Is there any reason this doesn't work as a shell script?

Comment: did you use your script with `sudo` permission? You must have an error printed in the terminal if the script failed, can you add it in your question?

Comment: Tried with and without sudo, I'll add the error now

Comment: It doesn't actually give an error, but no further commands are run.

Answer (score -1):

#### Bash command in docker

Welcome to Docker ;-) The command `docker run -it cli bash` starts the Docker image `cli` and than runs the `bash` command as login shell inside the container. This is way you get the `root@someaddress` prompt. So everything is as expected.

If you want to execute a command inside the container (and exit the container after that), use this:

```
docker run -it cli bash -c "echo hello from \$host; ls -la /"
```

Beware, quoting is important after the `-c` switch. If you need more information on the command_string checkout the [bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bash.1.html).

#### Run command(s) in container

There are many ways to get bash commands executed inside the container:

```
# mount the script into the container with -v
script=$(readlink -f myscript.sh)
docker run -it -v $script:$script cli bash $script

# use bash array to pass the commands into the container
cmd_list=()
cmd_list+=(echo cmd1)
cmd_list+=(echo cmd2)
cmd_list+=(echo done)
docker run -it cli bash -c "${cmd_list[*]}"

# google: bash here script
```

Comment: I think multiple commands are run inside the container. Will the -c cause the container to exit after the command in quotes?

Comment: yes, the container will always exit, when the command terminates

Comment: When you enter that command outside of a script, the container doesn't exit. Is it possible to run multiple commands like this?

Comment: That is what my example does: `-c "echo cmd1; echo cmd2; true && echo cmd3"`. You can also pipe full scripts to the bash... but that would be a bash no a docker question.

Comment: There are quire a few commands afterwards, and some are quite long. Is it possible to separate them out onto multiple lines rather than having them in quotes?

Comment: `docker exec …` runs a command in an existing container. `docker run … ` starts a command in an image (see `entrypoint` and `cmd`). That's a big difference.